# Sql server increasing order id manually

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

```
id name order
1   a     102
2   b     103
3   c     104
4   d     105
5   e     106
6   f     107
7   g     108
8   h     109
9   i     110
```

above showing like "order by order ASC"
column id is a primary key, auto increment by 1
column name is a varchar
colum order is an int

I want to update order numbers from a specified row.
for example,  I want to move id 9 to the first order (102) and want to change order numbers of all other ids for it.

is there way to do programmatically in ms sql ?

this is for my web site's product pages.
I would like to order products as I want....

EDIT: sorry this is my first time, I would like to explaing more.

First, for removing primary key, I dont want to change primary keys.
I just want to change their order ids, in above example, I want to change "order" of "id=9" to 102, then others needs to be follow up from 103,104,105 etc..

**RESULT** will be...

```
id name order
9   i     **102**
1   a     **103**
2   b     **104**
3   c     **105**
4   d     **106**
5   e     **107**
6   f     **108**
7   g     **109**
8   h     **110**
```

Comment: Please provide an example on how the result should be after

Comment: The question is vague and I'm not really sure what they are after.  However, it is usually a very bad design to be updating keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should not mess with an id (primary key) of a row. It should be immutable

If you need a custom sorting it is enough to add a new column

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MYTABLENAME ADD
    Sort int NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_tmp_Sort DEFAULT 0
GO
```

so you can sort by it and change it as you like

**Update after question edit:**

ok now I understand your requirement:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.MYTABLENAME
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 9 THEN 0
              ELSE ID END ASC
```

**further (hope last) update**

you just need 2 simple UPDATE:

```
UPDATE dbo.MYTABLENAME SET order=order+1 WHERE order>=102;
UPDATE dbo.MYTABLENAME SET order=102 WHERE id=9;
```

Comment: thank you @giammin , I edited question to explain more, please check again.

Comment: thank you again, but you misunderstand me I dont want to select, I want to "update" all like the result table.

Answer (score 2):

To reshuffle your data so that 9 starts at 102 and everything that comes after 102 is changed to now start at 103, use this:

```
UPDATE SomeTable SET [Order] = [Order] + 1 WHERE [Order] >= 102;
UPDATE SomeTable SET [Order] = 102 WHERE ID = 9
```

Where SomeTable is your table name

Comment: This is good, but I wonder if the OP needs to leave anything after ID 9 alone.  Like if there was a row with ID 10 and order 111 then you don't need to increment it's order.

Comment: @juharr well I want all rows needs to be reshuffle . but I wonder is that be any performance problem with 5000 rows ? Is there a way to be more intelligent ?

Comment: @MehmetBuluş It could be more performant, but I doubt you'd notice with just 5,000 rows.